# LNK2001 error using extern int

Tags: c++, linker

I have this simple example and I can't get it to compile:

Three files: *my.h*, *my.cpp*, and *use.cpp*:

```
//my.h
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

---

```
//my.cpp
#include "my.h"
#include "../../stb_lib_facilities.h" //inlcudes cout, cin, etc

void print_foo(){
    cout << foo << endl;
}

void print(int i){
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

---

```
//use.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "my.h"

int main(){
    foo = 7;
    print_foo();
    print(99);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it I get three errors:
LNK2001: extern "int foo"..
LNK2019: extern "int foo"..
LNK1120:

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have any *definition* of your global variable. In any of your `.cpp` files, but just in **one** of them, you should add this:

```
int foo = 0; // This is a definition
```

Your *declaration*:

```
extern int foo; // This is a declaration
```

Only tells the compiler that such a global variable exists, but then there is no place where you actually define it. Therefore, the linker will eventually complain that you have an undefined referenced symbol.